# settings.py does not exist django

Tags: python, django, bash, terminal

Running Python 2.7 Mac OSX.

I did:

```
django-admin.py startproject test123
cd test123
open settings.py
```

**Error:** `/users.../test123/settings.py` does not exist.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default django creates folder named `test123` if doesn't exists, and then puts settings in python package called `test123` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#startproject

So your settings will be in `test123` subfolder of `test123`

```
django-admin.py startproject test123
cd test123
ls -la
open test123/settings.py
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Appreciated